# jquery ajax post ответ

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Я столкнулся с проблемой, отсылаю данные с помощью $.ajax(), в ответ получаю сгенерированный pdf, но получаю и вижу его содержимое. Как сию бяку превратить в загрузку файла или открыть в браузере без перезагрузки страницы источника?

Либо есть второй вариант, по которому я пошел, но столкнулся с проблемой слишком длинного URI, так как данные посылаемые с помощью GET слишком велики

```
window.open("report.php?"+ s);
```

Вопрос как вышележачую конструкцию переделать в POST?

Comment: может сгенерированный пдф хранить на сервере и отсылать ссылку на него в ответе?

Comment: Тоже вариант, наверное пожалуй лучший для меня, хоть и костылем попахивает)

Answer (score 2):

может просто получать урл на файл в ответе например site.dev/file.pdf , а потом выполнять window.location.href = url_from_ajax, браузер будет предлагать загрузить или открыть документ

Comment: Как вариант кстати да, но хотелось бы без промежуточного хранения.

Answer (score 0):

там в PHP где обрабатываешь запрос, при выводе напиши

```
header("Cache-Control: ");
header("Content-type: application/pdf ");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.ССЫЛКА НА СВОЙ ФАЙЛ.'"');
```

Вот только не помню, нужно что-то выводить после Последнего Header, а так должно сработать и пользователю откроется окно  и предложат скачать файл с сервака.

Comment: Сомнительно, что AJAX запрос вдруг станет загружать файл...

Comment: Во во. Касательно заголовков их генерирует TCPDF так, что в них проблем нет он и так генерирует на закачку так как при использовании window.open("report.php?"+ s); закачка работает на ура - минус в ограничении длины url

Comment: так йопта в чем трабла тогда, правой кнопкой мыши на ссылке -> сохранить как, и как в старые добрые времена сохранять.

Возьмите да попробуйте! Если у вас не работает, то это не ко мне.
Я так POST запросом к серваку получаю сгенирированный файл на скачку.

Comment: @Shrek, Тут вопрос именно про AJAX ( а не iframe, script, etc... ) - крайне сомнительно, что используя технологию передачи "текста", можно расчитывать, что будет вызван ( неизвестно почему ) обработчик скачивания файлов.

Comment: Проблема в том, что длина get запроса конечна.

Comment: Возьми и попробуй! у меня все на Jquery. отправляем POST на сервак в ответ получаем файл на скачку.

Давайте начнём спорить "у кого пиписька больше" может флуда будет меньше и все загрузят сюда фотки хехе  :)

//UPD  отправь POST раз нехватка длины запроса или обязательное условие GET?

Comment: @Shrek я пробовал в ответ на $.ajax() приходит текстовое содержимое pdf файла. Я наверное что-то недогоняю. Мне надо не ajax, а просто послать post запрос без асинхронности. Если да - то чем? Так вот я и спрашиваю аналог функции, но с методом POST window.open("report.php?"+ s), где я прилепил get ручками.
@timka_s - Я согласен это сработает, но неужели нельзя проще? Да ничего просто, капризы.

Comment: @culebre - скрытая форма в iframe

UPD: а что тут сложного?)

Comment: @culebre да не может приходить текст!
если что-то и придет на выход то сразу целый файл на скачку.

а если вопрос уже стоит так "Мне надо не ajax, а просто послать post запрос без асинхронности." тогда меняй тему а я пойду попью чайку.

Answer (score 0):

Хм, а зачем ajax ? Если придет заголовок от сервера с типом "файл", то не волнуйтесь, на страницу с содержимым файла пользователь не попадет :))) => Ваш велосипед, который Вы собираете будет иметь квадратные колеса, а вместо седла - подсидел :)))

Да все просто, архитектура следующая:

1. php скрипт.
2. tmp папка

Функции php скрипта:

1. Генерация содержимого в файл и его сохранение в tmp папку.
2. Передача контента с заголовками, которые описал **Shrek**.
3. Удаление файла после окончания передачи.

Передача файла может осуществляться с помощью CURL. Т.е. после curl_close() мы удаляем файл, чтобы он не занимал место в tmp.

Вот и вся архитектура :)

Что же касается Вашего JS.... отправляйте запрос сабмитом и выполняйте при этом return false; :)

Comment: По моему, велосипед здесь предлагаете вы, архитектура велосипедных проектов так и строится, на огромном количестве ненужных шагов в вашем случае их 2 из 3. Вы сохраняете и удаляете файл - две абсолютно ненужных некрасивых операции. И в моем случае window.open("report.php?"+ s) выдает мне файл без всякого сохранения, проблема в том, что s передается через GET. Он ограничен. Неужели нет альтернативы через POST?! Я сомневаюсь. 

И если придет заголовок от сервера с типом "файл" - попадет, по крайней мере если это ajax, то будет headers already sent в лучшем случае.